# How to add a rule for a negative page state match (using the declarative content API)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to show my page action when the tab's URL *doesn't* contain a specified keyword.

This is an example showing a rule for a positive match for '.gif' in the `pathSuffix`.

```
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
{   
    conditions: [
            new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                    pageUrl: { pathSuffix: '.gif' },
            })  
    ],  

    actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
}
```

Is it possible to use this API to add a rule for when the page state *doesn't* match a certain string (e.g. to show the page action for all URLs except URLs with a specified suffix such as '.jpg')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Then again, the purpose of `declarativeContent` is to offload the checking to native code when the condition is infrequent (as it's more efficient than invoking JS). Since your negative condition is bound to activate almost everywhere (so expensive actions will occur nevertheless), the gain is much lessened. You're better off listening to [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated).

Also, please note that an action that makes sense on all or most pages is, [by Google guidelines](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#tips), better off as a Browser Action and not Page Action:

> - **Do** use page actions for features that make sense for only a few pages.
> - **Don't** use page actions for features that make sense for most pages. Use browser actions instead.

Comment: My page action should only be shown on URLs containing a certain suffix, except on some domains where it should never be shown. I think a page action is better in this case than a browser action. Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: I thought for a moment that `urlMatches` can help, but unfortunately a negative regex may not exist, as RE2 does not support negative look-arounds. So yeah, disregard my (deleted) comment.

Comment: Yeah, I had already tried that, probably should've put it in the question.